# Second use of getline

Tags: c

```
int get_int(){//gets an integer 
  size_t readint;
  size_t numbytes;

  char *input;
  int inint;
  int num;

  input = NULL;
  numbytes = 0;
  readint = getline(&input, &numbytes, stdin);
  if (readint == 0){
    num = 0;

  }else{
    num = atoi(input);//string to integer

  }
  return num;
   }
int exit_program(){//allows to finish and exit the program

  char c;
  printf("\nAre you sure you want to exit?(y/n) ");
  c = get_char();
  if(c == 'y' || c == 'Y'){
    exit(0);}else{
 if(c =='n' || c == 'N'){
      show_menu(); 
     }}return 0;
}

void show_menu(){//choose the option
  int option; 
printf("Type an option: \n");
    option = get_int();     
    switch(option){
        case 1: exit_program(); break;
        case 2: //create_jedi(&head); break;

        case 3: //show_jedis(head); break;

        case 4: puts("To be implemented"); break;

        case 5: puts("To be implemented"); break;

        default: printf("Invalid option"); break;
    }}

main(){
show_menu();}
```

The code is supposed to ask for a value. If you select '1', it asks you if you want to exit the program. If the answer is no, the program must ask you again for a value, however, it asigns 0 as an option, so it is an invalid option. 
I couldn't find the mistake, please help.

Comment: Who `free()`s all the memory `getline()` allocates? Why not just read an integer using `scanf()`? Also, whats the purpose of the return value of `show_menu()` since it only ever returns `0` which doesn't get evaluated by `show_menu()`? You are calling `show_menu()` recursively from `exit_program()` ... why do you do that? if you wouldn't it would return to `show_menu()` anyway.

Comment: What is `get_char()`? Does it read just one character? If so, you will have problems because you won't read the end-of-line after the y/n reply. When you ask a question and expect a reply from the user, you are probably expecting the reply to take the form of a line. if so, you should use some function that reads a line. If the user pushes "y<enter>" and you only read the "y", the enter is stuck in the input buffer to be read later when you don't expect it.

Comment: That Pico-esque (but not even consistently Pico) style of indentation is abominable — do not use it in C code posted to SO.  Use either Allman (my preferred style) or a variant of 1TBS — see Wikipedia on [Indentation Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style).

Comment: Do not use `num = atoi(input);`, `atoi` provides ZERO error checking for the conversion. Instead use `strtol` or `sscanf`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: `scanf()` and family don't handle integer overflow any better than `atoi()` does.  Using `strtol()` or one of its variants is reasonable.

Comment: Good point, but at least `sscanf` knows the difference between `"abc"` and `"123"` and provides a return to discern between the two.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you can limit the number of digits to read and thus artificially limit the value to something < INT_MAX

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void clear_stream(FILE *is)  // clears garbage from the stream after
{                            // a failed input operation
    int ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(is)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
}

// reads an integer from stdin until it is within the range min, max
int get_int(int min, int max, char const *prompt)
{
    int number;
    while (prompt && printf("%s", prompt),
           scanf("%d", &number) != 1 || number < min || max < number)
    {
        fputs("Input error :(\n\n", stderr);
        clear_stream(stdin);
    }
    return number;
}

// reads a character from stdin until it is within range (if range != null)
char get_char(char const *range, char const *prompt)
{
    char ch;
    while (prompt && printf("%s", prompt),
           scanf(" %c", &ch) != 1 || range && !strchr(range, ch) )
           //     ^ skips leading whitespace
    {
        fputs("Input error :(\n\n", stderr);
        clear_stream(stdin);
    }
    return ch;
}

// asks user if he is sure to exit the program and returns true if that is so
bool exit_program()
{
    char choice = get_char("yYnN",
        "\nAre you sure you want to exit?\n"
        "[y] Yes\n"
        "[n] No\n\n"
        "> ");
    return choice == 'y' || choice == 'Y';
}

void show_menu()
{
    bool do_exit = false;  // false until the user decides otherwise.
    do {
        int choice = get_int(1, 4,
            "\n[1] Exit\n"
            "[2] Function A\n"
            "[3] Function B\n"
            "[4] Function C\n\n"
            "> ");

        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            do_exit = exit_program();
            break;

        case 2:
            puts("Function A\n");
            break;

        case 3:
            puts("Function B\n");
            break;

        case 4:
            puts("Function C\n");
            break;
        }
    } while (!do_exit);
}

int main(void)
{
    show_menu();
}
```

#### Sample output:

```
[1] Exit
[2] Function A
[3] Function B
[4] Function C

Type an option: 1

Are you sure you want to exit?
[y] Yes
[n] No

> f
Input error :(


Are you sure you want to exit?
[y] Yes
[n] No

> asldjkflkasdjf
Input error :(


Are you sure you want to exit?
[y] Yes
[n] No

> n

[1] Exit
[2] Function A
[3] Function B
[4] Function C

Type an option: 2
Function A


[1] Exit
[2] Function A
[3] Function B
[4] Function C

Type an option: 3
Function B


[1] Exit
[2] Function A
[3] Function B
[4] Function C

Type an option: 4
Function C


[1] Exit
[2] Function A
[3] Function B
[4] Function C

Type an option: 1

Are you sure you want to exit?
[y] Yes
[n] No

> n

[1] Exit
[2] Function A
[3] Function B
[4] Function C

Type an option: 2
Function A


[1] Exit
[2] Function A
[3] Function B
[4] Function C

Type an option: 1

Are you sure you want to exit?
[y] Yes
[n] No

> y
```

Comment: Good clean up. Only nit is `EOF` (user canceling input with Ctrl+d, or Ctrl+z on windows) isn't handled.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `^d` and `^z` are not valid options ;p

Comment: No, but that doesn't stop the user from pressing them thinking he can cancel that input. Either way you are covered with the invalid input error that's why I said it was just a "nit".